# storing form fields using cookies or localstorage across pages

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have 3 pages in my app that have a set of questions. Each page has roughly 6 questions that a user needs to answer and then click next. Now, when the user clicks previous, they should be able to see the typed data in the fields. I have used the concept of cookies in my code and written the getcookies and setcookies functions according to the sample code in this link,
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/

Here is my code,

```
 <script>
            // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
            // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

             var today = new Date();
             var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

             function setCookie(name, value)
  {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }
  function storeValues(form)  
  {
    setCookie("1.Your GPA from previous degree", form.field1.value);
    setCookie("2.Your GRE/GMAT score", form.field2.value);
    setCookie("2.Your GRE/GMAT score", form.field3.value);
    setCookie("3.Your TOEFL/IELTS score", form.field4.value);
    setCookie("3.Your TOEFL/IELTS score", form.field5.value);
    setCookie("4.Number of backlogs from your previous degree", form.field6.value);
    return true;
  }
  function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }

</script>
```

`
After the above script is the form code with lots of drop downs and text boxes. The first page contains 6 questions but they are in the following manner,

[This is how the first page with the questions looks like, notice how the 2nd 3rd questions have 2 separate drop downs? I am not sure how to place them in terms of the ids in the functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ft5A.png)

There is also a validation script in place that checks if the user has entered all the mandatory fields and it is added in the next button's onclick event like so, onclick = "javascript:validate();"

I need help in finding out what I am doing wrong. I know I am not entirely correct in the area where I need to grab the elements by id/name. Please take a look at the image to understand where I am coming from, regarding the ids/names of the fields. Any help is appreciated.

I am posting the form code in here too,

```
 <form action = "POST" name="qform">
                    <div class="question clearfix form-group form-inline">
                      <label class="col-sm-4">1. Your GPA from previous degree <span class="text-danger">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                        <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                        <select id="gpa"  class="form-control" onfocus required>
    //a huge drop down here..

                    <div class="question clearfix form-group form-inline">
                    <label class="col-sm-4">2. Your GRE/GMAT score <span class="text-danger">&nbsp;*</label>
                        <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                        <select id="greScore" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Your GRE Score</option>
    //a huge drop down here
    <select id="gmatScore" class="form-control ml">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Your GMAT Score</option>
    //a huge drop down here
    <div class="question clearfix form-group form-inline">
                      <label class="col-sm-4">3. Your TOEFL/IELTS score<span class="text-danger">&nbsp;*</label></label>
                        <p class="col-sm-7">
                        <select id="toeflScore" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Your TOEFL Score</option>
    //a huge drop down here
    <select id="ieltsScore" class="form-control ml">
                        <!-- change scores -->
                            <option value="0" selected="selected">Your IELTS Score</option>
                            <option value="1">5</option>
                            <option value="2">5.5</option>
                            <option value="3">6</option>
                            <option value="4">6.5</option>
                            <option value="5">7</option>
                            <option value="6">7.5</option>
                            <option value="7">8</option>
                            <option value="8">8.5</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>                    
                        </select> 
                    </p>
                    </div>             
                    <div class="question form-group">
                     <label class="col-sm-4">
                    4. Number of backlogs from your previous degree
                    </label>
                    <p class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" id="backlog" class="form-control">
                    </p>
                    </div> 
                    </form>
```

Please also look at the link to the image I gave of the form(the first page).

Comment: For better understanding, you need to paste source of the form.

Comment: Sure, here's the form code

Comment: <form action = "POST" name="qform">
    <div class="question clearfix form-group form-inline">
                  <label class="col-sm-4">1. Your GPA from previous degree <span class="text-danger">&nbsp;*</span></label>
                    <p class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                    <select id="gpa"  class="form-control" onfocus required>

Comment: im sorry...figuring out how to post code in here

Comment: i have added the form code in the original post